# How to split a string based on two regex formats?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to split a string into an array based on two different regex delimiters, integers and non-integers, but I can't seem to get the results I want.

I have tried different combinations of `string.split(regex)` without success. If I use `([^0-9]+)` I can successfully separate all non-integers together into its own array, but the integers are lost. If I try to do a combination of `([^0-9]+)([0-9]+)`I end up with strange results and not the desired output.

My first attempt was splitting the string by character, so each character no matter what type it is, is a different item on the array `string.split("")` but I need numbers grouped together to manipulate, and must retain the original string by the end.

Given the string:

`He1l0oo, th111s is my r@nd0m 86 str1ng`

the output should be:

`[He], [1], [l], [0], [oo, th], [111], [s is my r@nd], [0], [m ], [86], [ str], [1], [ng]`

but I only get:

`[1], [0], [111], [0], [86], [1]`

I need both the non-integer and integer groups in the output so I can join the string back together in the same format, and with this output I lose everything else. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `String.split()` gives you only the pieces *between* delimiters.  The delimiters themselves -- the substrings that match the pattern -- are omitted.  But you don't have actual delimiters in your string.  Rather, you want to split at transitions between digits and non-digits.  These can be matched via zero-width assertions:

```
string.split("(?<![0-9])(?=[0-9])|(?<=[0-9])(?![0-9])");
```

That is

- the position after a non-digit `(?<![0-9])` and before a digit `(?=[0-9])`

or (`|`)

- the position after a digit `(?<=[0-9])` and before a non-digit `(?![0-9])`

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. I have only used basic regex for simple tasks in the past, and was trying to match groups without realizing I needed to set specific delimiters between both. This was very helpful, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the regex

```
"(?:\\d+|\\D+)"
```

This matches a group of digits *or* a digit of non-digits, but not both.

Roughly, the code will look like the following:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:\\d+|\\D+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("He1l0oo, th111s is my r@nd0m 86 str1ng");

List<String> groups = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    groups.add(matcher.group());
}

System.out.println(groups);
```

Comment: Have a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html) for more information on how to use the `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes.